# Design Pattern for returning Connection Object

Tags: java, design-patterns, paas

We are working on PAAS applications (Spring Boot) which have 2-3 different modules in which each module has some redundant code for creating and closing database and MQ connections.

We are using Hikari DataSource for maintaining pool connections, and are planning to centralize the code which contains configuration data, putting that as a parent dependency in others.

Is there any suitable java design pattern which fulfills this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably either Factory Design Pattern or Abstract factory design pattern; They are conceptually almost same. UML diagram of it [Factory Design Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrBU7.jpg)

The Abstract Factory Design Pattern sounds fancier, but isn't anything more complex than the Factory Design Pattern. [Abstract Factory Design Pattern.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwEF1.jpg)

Comment: My beans of dbconnection will be created during context up only using the configuration data and only i will be using that bean in the whole project again and again . Will in this scenario Abstract factory will be usable? Because its main purpose is to hide object creation from "subclasses".

Comment: I reckon, it would.

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot no need to create new class using a design pattern, spring handle itself. only need to following propertis in application.propertis

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, I assume that it would be a good idea to create one class which handles the connections and annotate it with an `@Component` annotation. You can then refer to the class by using the `@Autowired` annotation in your other classes. for example:

```
@Component
public class MyDataSource {
    // ....
}
```

Spring boot can automatically wire the component into other classes as follows (notice the `@Autowired` annotation above the constructor):

```
public class SomeServiceUsingTheDataSource {
    private final MyDataSource myDataSource;

    @Autowired
    public SomeServiceUsingTheDataSource(MyDataSource myDataSource) {
          this.myDataSource = myDataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to use design pattern so that in each and every class I need not to autowire the class again & again. This solution is good for small set of classes.

Comment: You might want to add some code samples to clarify this question. The only thing I can think of would be to create your own DataSource bean: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html or to use a singleton pattern.